# merge multiple projects into one project?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

Is it possible to merge multiple projects into one project using Flutter? same as uber and uber eats.

[example, uber ride and uber eats both apps one same app](https://specials-images.forbesimg.com/imageserve/5d8d026b6c7c8f0009906aeb/960x0.jpg?fit=scale)

Answer (score 0):

This is related to architecture of project, if that is modular components you can merge projects by take some time.

Comment: you mean, is it one app? (please check my url)